# Laravel Update Query with multiple columns, Conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Can we update multiple columns based on multiple different condition in Laravel using Eloquent
Lets Say, I want to

```
Design::where('name','A')->update(['override_value'=>'some_value1']);

Design::where('name','B')->update(['override_value'=>'some_value2']);

Design::where('name','C')->update(['override_value'=>'some_value3']);
```

Do i have to repeat this query or is there a way to do this in a single update query ?

Comment: your question is bit unclear , but from what i can understand you want to update different column based on different condition??

Comment: That is right ! i need to update multiple fields of same table ,
i need to update table 
Design where column "name" Has value "A" and set "override_value" to "SomeValue1" AND  column "name" Has value "B" and set "override_value" to "SomeValue2"

Comment: understand  this, if you   have different condition for updating field every time , what you can do is create model scope and pass the array  for both where condition and update

Comment: its going to happen in a single post request, right now i have to run 5 queries on same table one after another, doesn't seem to be the right way of hitting a table 5 times continuously

Comment: please share some more details , so i can help you out

Comment: This is current code:
WebsiteRebranding::where('name','logo')->update(["override_value" => $filename]);WebsiteRebranding::where('name','homepage_topbanner_image')->update(["override_value" => $filenameBanner]);
                   WebsiteRebranding::where('name','primary_color')->update(["override_value" => $request->primary_color]);
                   WebsiteRebranding::where('name','navbar')->update(["override_value" => $request->navbar]);
                   WebsiteRebranding::where('name','secondary_color')->update(["override_value" => $request->secondary_color]);

Comment: there must be a better way to write this

Comment: Is the name field unique in your table? If so I have the solution you need

Comment: yes its unique.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've added my answer and explaination for you. I hope I made it clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Use query builder [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) clause

e.g.

```
DB::table('designs')->whereIn('name', ['A', 'B', 'C'])->update(['override_value'=>'some_value']);
```

another way if you need different values is by using [upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts)

e.g.

```
Design::upsert([
    ['name' => 'A', 'override_value' => 'some_value1'],
    ['name' => 'B', 'override_value' => 'some_value2'],
    ['name' => 'C', 'override_value' => 'some_value3'],
], ['name'], ['override_value']);
```

just make sure the name already exist in your tables, otherwise it will create new record

Comment: It could be used if i had to update  columns A,B,C with same value, but my value for column A ,B,C is different.

Comment: you need to provide proper example, and your code logic, I'm only answering based on your example

Comment: @SikanderSharma I edited my answer, just use `upsert` to update multiple columns with different values

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, using `whereIn` method and passing an array with multiple values in `update` method as first parameter.

```
 Design::whereIn('name', ['A', 'B'])->update(['override_value'=>'some_value', 'some_other_value' => 'new value']);
```

Comment: need to change override_value where( name = A )override_value ="XYZ")AND  where( name = B )override_value ="ABC")

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do that in one line, your data must be an associative array like this

```php
$data = [
    "A" => "some_value1",
    "B" => "some_value2",
    "C" => "some_value3",
];
```

and then loop through it and update the records like this

```php
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    Design::where('name', $key)->update(['override_value' => $value]);
}
```

Comment: This will execute a query per item, this is not what OP wants and should usually be avoided due to the n+1 query problem it will cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [upsert()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts), I've used them alot to update thousands of records, all with their own changes. The only requirement to use it is that you can only specify the identifiers with actual unique keys. Check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts) for more info.

```
//An array to store the changes in.
$updates = [];
//You can fill the $updates array by looping over db-data that you want to manipulate 
//For simplicity sake i'm gonna fill them manually
$updates[] = [
  'name' => 'A',//identifier. Please note you can also use id if you have no other unique key
  'override_value' => 'X'//insert what you want to change for this identifier
];
$updates[] = [
  'name' => 'B',
  'override_value' => 'Y'
];
$updates[] = [
  'name' => 'C',
  'override_value' => 'Z'
];
//Upsert 
//First parameter expects the array with identifiers and updates
//Second parameter is list of keys to identify the record.
//Third parameter is list of keys to update
Design::upsert($updates, ['name'], ['override_value']);
```

Just beware that using upsert does not throw events on the model! Some libraries will require models to throw events(like laravel-auditing)

Comment: i think this is what i am looking for, i tried this but it creates new rows in DB , do i have to make "name" unique in DB ?

Comment: Depending on where you get the changes from, you can also use the id field in stead of the name field( if you dont wanna make name unique). It stores updates and new records in one go, which is 9 out if 10 time what you need anyway. If you don't want this behavior, you need to filter your array before upserting it.